# Swift: Adding NSLayoutConstraint Issues

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to create layout constraint between a `tableView` and view controller's `view`. Basically the `tableView` is directly inside the main view.

Here:

```
let leftConstant = CGFloat(250.0) 

let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: menuTableView,
     attribute: .Top,
     relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: self.topLayoutGuide,
     attribute: .Bottom,
    multiplier: 1,
     constant: 0.0)

let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: menuTableView,
    attribute: .LeadingMargin,
    relatedBy: .Equal,
       toItem: view,
    attribute: .LeadingMargin,
   multiplier: 1,
     constant: -leftConstant)

let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: menuTableView,
    attribute: .Bottom,
    relatedBy: .Equal,
       toItem: self.bottomLayoutGuide,
    attribute: .Top,
   multiplier: 1,
     constant: 0.0)

let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: menuTableView,
    attribute: .Width,
    relatedBy: .Equal,
       toItem: nil,
    attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
   multiplier: 0,
     constant: leftConstant)

let verticalCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: menuTableView,
    attribute: .CenterX,
    relatedBy: .Equal,
       toItem: view,
    attribute: .CenterX,
   multiplier: 1,
     constant: 0.0)

menuTableView.addConstraints([topConstraint, leftConstraint, bottomConstraint, widthConstraint, verticalCenterConstraint])
```

...and I'm getting this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16d18490 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x16d24de0]-(0)-[UITableView:0x172a3800]> view:<UITableView: 0x172a3800; frame = (0 0; 250 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16e23190>; layer = <CALayer: 0x16e24e20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {250, 74}>'
```

Comment: It's not a solution to your question but an advice: I would recommend you to try out the new auto layout syntax for iOS 9. This will shorten your code a lot. :)

Comment: Try from this reference link http://stackoverflow.com/a/31202774/3792386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add constraint of `menuTableView` to itself, by replace

```
menuTableView.addConstraints([topConstraint, leftConstraint, bottomConstraint, widthConstraint, verticalCenterConstraint])
```

with

```
menuTableView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
```

---

and add these constraint to `view`

```
view.addConstraints([topConstraint, leftConstraint, bottomConstraint])
```

because the view that holds the constraint must be an ancestor of the views the constraint involves

**and you must choose either `.Leading` or `.CenterX`, otherwise you will get `unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`.